# How to find unique lines in Unix file by negelecting a specific pattern

Tags: unix

I have a file in Unix like the follows

```
">hello"
"hello"
"newuser"
"<newuser"
"newone"
```

Now I want to find unique occurrences in the file (exluding the `<` or `>` only while searching) and the output as:

```
">hello"
"<newuser"
"newone"
```

Comment: Have you typed `man uniq` at your terminal?

Comment: uniq will do much, but not all of this.  You could ignore the > and < by removing them with sed and piping through uniq, but then the > < won't appear in the output.

Comment: You can also use an associative array in a language like perl or python to keep a cache of the strings seen so far.  This cache can be used to decide when new lines are unique.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
seen = set()
for line in sys.stdin:
    word = line.strip().replace('>', '').replace('<', '')
    if word not in seen:
        seen.add(word)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

---

```
$ ./uniq.py < file1
">hello"
"newuser"
"newone"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{ w = $1; sub(/[<>]/, "", w) } word[w] == 0 { word[w]++; print $1 }' file1
">hello"
"newuser"
"newone"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's that associative array idea in Ruby.

```
2.0.0p195 :005 > entries= [">hello", "hello", "newuser", "<newuser", "newone"]
 => [">hello", "hello", "newuser", "<newuser", "newone"] 
2.0.0p195 :006 > entries.reduce({}) { |hash, entry| hash[entry.sub(/[<>]/,'')]=entry; hash}.values
 => ["hello", "<newuser", "newone"]
```